# Error using built in gabor filters in scikit-image in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

Iam trying to use built-in filters in python using scikit image. 
However on executing this sample code,

```
    from skimage import data, io, filters
    image = data.coins() # or any NumPy array!
    edges = filters.sobel(image)
    io.imshow(edges)
    io.show()
```

I get the error: " from skimage import data, io, filters 
ImportError: cannot import name filters". 
I have scikit image package listed in my project interpreter.How to resolve this error?

Comment: You might not have the components `filters` installed.

Comment: please guide me as to how to do that?

Comment: The "filters" module was known as "filter" in older versions of scikit-image, so perhaps you haven't upgraded to 0.11 yet.  The rename was to prevent clobbering Python's built-in.

Comment: Just to add to @Stefan van der Walt's comment, you can check your scikit-image version with `import skimage; skimage.__version__` if it's lower than `0.11` then use `filter` instead of `filters` as stefan suggested.